# Tables Falling Off Page in Mobile View

Tags: html, css, flexbox, multiple-columns

I am creating a calendar page for a simple website. My page is finished and looks good in desktop view. When I check to see if the page is responsive, the tables fall off the page in mobile view. I do not know why my code is not working to change the 2 columns to 1 column in mobile view. I would appreciate if anyone could point out what is wrong with my code and how I can fix it.

```css
.Calendar, th,td{
    color: black; 
    border: 1px solid navy;
    background-color: #add8e6;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-bottom:1%;
    margin-top:1%;  
}

.eventDay{
    background-color:red;
}

.div_left, .div_right{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow:column;
}
.row_main{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.column{
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count:2;
    column-count: 2;
    display: flex;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
    .column{
        -moz-column-count:1;
        -webkit-column-count:1;
        column-count:1;
    }
    .row_main:{
        flex-flow:column;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="row_main">
<div class="column">
<div class="div_left">
<table class="Calendar">
  <tr>
  <th colspan="8">January 2021</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sun</th> 
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tues</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thurs</th>
    <th>Fri</th> 
    <th>Sat</th> 
    <th>Important Dates</th>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">1</td></div>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>New Years </td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>17</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">18</td></div>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>Martin Luther King Day</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>28</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">29</td></div>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>Safety Meeing</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>31</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr> 
  

  
  </table>
 

   <table class="Calendar">
  <tr>
  <th colspan="8">February 2021</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sun</th> 
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tues</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thurs</th>
    <th>Fri</th> 
    <th>Sat</th> 
    <th>Important Dates</th>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>14</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">15</td></div>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>Presidents' Day</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>28</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  </table>

  <table class="Calendar">
  <tr>
  <th colspan="8">March 2021</th>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <th>Sun</th> 
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tues</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thurs</th>
    <th>Fri</th> 
    <th>Sat</th> 
    <th>Important Dates</th>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">26</td></div>
    <td>27</td>
    <td> Safety Meeting</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>31</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  
 <table class="Calendar">
  <tr>
  <th colspan="8">April 2021</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sun</th> 
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tues</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thurs</th>
    <th>Fri</th> 
    <th>Sat</th> 
    <th>Important Dates</th>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">2</td></div>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Good Friday</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
   </table>
   
 <table class="Calendar">
  <tr>
  <th colspan="8">May 2021</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sun</th> 
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tues</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thurs</th>
    <th>Fri</th> 
    <th>Sat</th> 
    <th>Important Dates</th>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">28</td></div>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>Safety Meeting</td>
  </tr>
 
 <tr>
    <td>30</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">31</td></div>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Memorial Day</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="Calendar">
  <tr>
  <th colspan="8">June 2021</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sun</th> 
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tues</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thurs</th>
    <th>Fri</th> 
    <th>Sat</th> 
    <th>Important Dates</th>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">12</td></div>
    <td>12th-13th:Annual Sales Meeting</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td><div class="eventDay">13</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">14</td></div>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>Flag Day</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr> 
</table>
 </th>
</div>
  </div>
<div class="column"> 
  <div class="div_right">
<table class="Calendar">
  <tr>
  <th colspan="8">July 2021</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sun</th> 
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tues</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thurs</th>
    <th>Fri</th> 
    <th>Sat</th>
    <th>Important Dates</th>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td><div class="eventDay">4</td></div>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">10</td></div>
    <td>Independence Day</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td><div class="eventDay">11</td></div>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>10th-11th:Company Picnic</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">30</td></div>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>Safety Meeting</td>
  </tr>
 </table> 
 
  <table class="Calendar">
  <tr>
  <th colspan="8">August 2021</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sun</th> 
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tues</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thurs</th>
    <th>Fri</th> 
    <th>Sat</th> 
    <th>Important Dates</th>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">7</td></div>
    <td> Bicycle Club Fundraisor </td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>28</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>31</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  
  <table class="Calendar">
  <tr>
  <th colspan="8">September 2021</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sun</th> 
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tues</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thurs</th>
    <th>Fri</th> 
    <th>Sat</th> 
    <td>Important Dates</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">6</td></div>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>Labor Day</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">24</td></div>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>Safety Meeting</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  
 <table class="Calendar">
  <tr>
  <th colspan="8">October 2021</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sun</th> 
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tues</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thurs</th>
    <th>Fri</th> 
    <th>Sat</th> 
    <th>Important Dates</th>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">11</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">12</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">13</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">14</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">15</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">16</td></div>
    <td>11th: Columbus Day</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td><div class="eventDay">17</td></div>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>12th-17th:Annual Convention</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>31</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  
  <table class="Calendar">
  <tr>
  <th colspan="8">November 2021</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sun</th> 
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tues</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thurs</th>
    <th>Fri</th> 
    <th>Sat</th>
    <th>Important Dates</th>    
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">11</td></div>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>Veterans Day</th>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">24</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">25</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">26</td></div>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>Thanksgiving Break</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>28</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">29</td></div>
    <td>30</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Safety Meeting</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  
 <table class="Calendar">
<tr>
  <th colspan="8">December 2021</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sun</th> 
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tues</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thurs</th>
    <th>Fri</th> 
    <th>Sat</th> 
    <th>Important Dates</th>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">1</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">2</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">3</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">4</td></div>
    <td>Toys For Tots</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td><div class="eventDay">5</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">6</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">7</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">8</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">9</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">10</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">11</td></div>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td><div class="eventDay">12</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">13</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">14</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">15</td></div>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td><div class="eventDay">25</td></div>
    <td>Christmas</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td><div class="eventDay">26</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">27</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">28</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">29</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">30</td></div>
    <td><div class="eventDay">31</td></div>
    <td></td>
    <td>Winter Break</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `flex-direction: column;` for the `.row_main` container in the media queries for mobile to place the flex items *below*  each other (instead of the default which places them next to each other, i.e. in a horizontal line)

```css
.Calendar,
th,
td {
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid navy;
  background-color: #add8e6;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  margin-top: 1%;
}

.eventDay {
  background-color: red;
}

.div_left,
.div_right {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.row_main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.column {
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  display: flex;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .row_main {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .column {
    -moz-column-count: 1;
    -webkit-column-count: 1;
    column-count: 1;
  }
  .row_main: {
    flex-flow: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row_main">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="div_left">
      <table class="Calendar">
        <tr>
          <th colspan="8">January 2021</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Sun</th>
          <th>Mon</th>
          <th>Tues</th>
          <th>Wed</th>
          <th>Thurs</th>
          <th>Fri</th>
          <th>Sat</th>
          <th>Important Dates</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">1</td>
          </div>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>New Years </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">18</td>
          </div>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>Martin Luther King Day</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">29</td>
          </div>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>Safety Meeing</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>31</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>



      </table>


      <table class="Calendar">
        <tr>
          <th colspan="8">February 2021</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Sun</th>
          <th>Mon</th>
          <th>Tues</th>
          <th>Wed</th>
          <th>Thurs</th>
          <th>Fri</th>
          <th>Sat</th>
          <th>Important Dates</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">15</td>
          </div>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>Presidents' Day</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>28</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <table class="Calendar">
        <tr>
          <th colspan="8">March 2021</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Sun</th>
          <th>Mon</th>
          <th>Tues</th>
          <th>Wed</th>
          <th>Thurs</th>
          <th>Fri</th>
          <th>Sat</th>
          <th>Important Dates</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">26</td>
          </div>
          <td>27</td>
          <td> Safety Meeting</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>31</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <table class="Calendar">
        <tr>
          <th colspan="8">April 2021</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Sun</th>
          <th>Mon</th>
          <th>Tues</th>
          <th>Wed</th>
          <th>Thurs</th>
          <th>Fri</th>
          <th>Sat</th>
          <th>Important Dates</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">2</td>
          </div>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>Good Friday</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>24</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <table class="Calendar">
        <tr>
          <th colspan="8">May 2021</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Sun</th>
          <th>Mon</th>
          <th>Tues</th>
          <th>Wed</th>
          <th>Thurs</th>
          <th>Fri</th>
          <th>Sat</th>
          <th>Important Dates</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">28</td>
          </div>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>Safety Meeting</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">31</td>
          </div>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>Memorial Day</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <table class="Calendar">
        <tr>
          <th colspan="8">June 2021</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Sun</th>
          <th>Mon</th>
          <th>Tues</th>
          <th>Wed</th>
          <th>Thurs</th>
          <th>Fri</th>
          <th>Sat</th>
          <th>Important Dates</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">12</td>
          </div>
          <td>12th-13th:Annual Sales Meeting</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">13</td>
          </div>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">14</td>
          </div>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>Flag Day</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>26</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </th>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="div_right">
      <table class="Calendar">
        <tr>
          <th colspan="8">July 2021</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Sun</th>
          <th>Mon</th>
          <th>Tues</th>
          <th>Wed</th>
          <th>Thurs</th>
          <th>Fri</th>
          <th>Sat</th>
          <th>Important Dates</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">4</td>
          </div>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">10</td>
          </div>
          <td>Independence Day</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">11</td>
          </div>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>10th-11th:Company Picnic</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>24</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">30</td>
          </div>
          <td>31</td>
          <td>Safety Meeting</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <table class="Calendar">
        <tr>
          <th colspan="8">August 2021</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Sun</th>
          <th>Mon</th>
          <th>Tues</th>
          <th>Wed</th>
          <th>Thurs</th>
          <th>Fri</th>
          <th>Sat</th>
          <th>Important Dates</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">7</td>
          </div>
          <td> Bicycle Club Fundraisor </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>28</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>31</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <table class="Calendar">
        <tr>
          <th colspan="8">September 2021</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Sun</th>
          <th>Mon</th>
          <th>Tues</th>
          <th>Wed</th>
          <th>Thurs</th>
          <th>Fri</th>
          <th>Sat</th>
          <td>Important Dates</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">6</td>
          </div>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>Labor Day</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">24</td>
          </div>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>Safety Meeting</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <table class="Calendar">
        <tr>
          <th colspan="8">October 2021</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Sun</th>
          <th>Mon</th>
          <th>Tues</th>
          <th>Wed</th>
          <th>Thurs</th>
          <th>Fri</th>
          <th>Sat</th>
          <th>Important Dates</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">11</td>
          </div>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">12</td>
          </div>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">13</td>
          </div>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">14</td>
          </div>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">15</td>
          </div>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">16</td>
          </div>
          <td>11th: Columbus Day</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">17</td>
          </div>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>12th-17th:Annual Convention</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>31</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <table class="Calendar">
        <tr>
          <th colspan="8">November 2021</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Sun</th>
          <th>Mon</th>
          <th>Tues</th>
          <th>Wed</th>
          <th>Thurs</th>
          <th>Fri</th>
          <th>Sat</th>
          <th>Important Dates</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">11</td>
          </div>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>Veterans Day</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">24</td>
          </div>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">25</td>
          </div>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">26</td>
          </div>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>Thanksgiving Break</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">29</td>
          </div>
          <td>30</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>Safety Meeting</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <table class="Calendar">
        <tr>
          <th colspan="8">December 2021</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Sun</th>
          <th>Mon</th>
          <th>Tues</th>
          <th>Wed</th>
          <th>Thurs</th>
          <th>Fri</th>
          <th>Sat</th>
          <th>Important Dates</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">1</td>
          </div>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">2</td>
          </div>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">3</td>
          </div>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">4</td>
          </div>
          <td>Toys For Tots</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">5</td>
          </div>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">6</td>
          </div>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">7</td>
          </div>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">8</td>
          </div>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">9</td>
          </div>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">10</td>
          </div>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">11</td>
          </div>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">12</td>
          </div>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">13</td>
          </div>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">14</td>
          </div>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">15</td>
          </div>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">25</td>
          </div>
          <td>Christmas</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">26</td>
          </div>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">27</td>
          </div>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">28</td>
          </div>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">29</td>
          </div>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">30</td>
          </div>
          <td>
            <div class="eventDay">31</td>
          </div>
          <td></td>
          <td>Winter Break</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```